# Is there any reason to buy the iWork bundle instead of the apps separately from the App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, iwork

Keynote is $19, Pages is $19, Numbers is $19. iWork bundle is $79.

Why would anyone want to buy the bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it's mostly here for people on Leopard and older version of Mac OS X. Since the Mac App Store only works in Snow Leopard and later.

It could also be for people who don't want to depend on an internet connection when they need to (re)install, and want to have the app physically at all time.

Comment: You need an internet connection to use the unbundled iWork apps?

Comment: To download them, yes. I've (hopefully) clarified my post.

Comment: For utpo 5 computers activation the offer it for 99$. If I buy via the app store, do I have to pay for each computer separately?

Comment: Look in the App Store Help menu, under Purchase applications > Use applications on multiple Macs: "After you purchase an application, you can install it free of charge on every Mac you use."

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple computers (and are one person) it's easier to buy iWork from the Mac App Store so you don't have to do some many different install processes. If you have multiple computers with multiple users then it's easier to buy iWork in it's box form.