# Is there a way for registering iWork apps on App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, iwork

I bought iWork 09 at the Apple Store and it is installed on my MacBook Pro.

However, since I didn't buy it on the Mac App Store, when I go to the Mac App Store purchased tab the iWork apps are not listed.

Is there a way to register them on Mac App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'll link to some of the questions that cover this. The App Store version is sold and licensed differently than the version licensed online.

- [Do I have to repurchase Apple apps through the Mac App Store to get updates there?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/do-i-have-to-repurchase-apple-apps-through-the-mac-app-store-to-get-updates-ther?rq=1)
- [Is there any reason to buy the iWork bundle instead of the apps separately from the App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11538/is-there-any-reason-to-buy-the-iwork-bundle-instead-of-the-apps-separately-from?rq=1)
- [Can I update apps that I've already purchased through the Mac App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/can-i-update-apps-that-ive-already-purchased-through-the-mac-app-store?rq=1)